# Identifying stochastic process through its autocovariance function

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, time-series

I am unable to understand how to correctly identify time series processes through their autocovariance functions (acvf).

For example I have an acvf $$\gamma(h) = \begin{cases} 4-|h|, & |h|\leq4,\\ 0, &|h|>4.\end{cases} $$ Apparently this is a moving average lag 3 process (MA(3)). Any directions on how to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about auto*covariance* functions of processes that might not ne zero-mean processes, but if a wide-sense stationary (a.k.a. weakly stationary) stochastic process $\{X_t\}$has auto*correlation* function $E[X_tX_{t+h}]$ given by
$$E[X_tX_{t+h}] = \gamma(h) = \begin{cases} 4-|h|, & |h|\leq 4,\\ 0, &|h|>4,\end{cases} $$
then we can immediately say that the process indeed has zero mean (and so its autocorrelation function coincides with its autocovariance function). Furthermore, since
$\gamma(h) = g\star \tilde{g}\big\vert_h$ where $\tilde{g}$ is the time-reverse of $g$, that is, $\tilde{g}(t) = g(-t)$, with $g(t) = \begin{cases}1, & 0 \leq t \leq  4,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$ for continuous-time processes, and $g(t) = \begin{cases}1, & t =0,1,2,3,\\ 0 & \text{otherwise},\end{cases}$ for discrete-time processes (a.k.a. time series), we can write that

$$X_t = \int_{t-4}^t W_{\tau} \,\mathrm d\tau ~~ \text{or} ~~ X_t = \sum_{\tau=0}^3 W_{t-\tau}$$

according as the process is a continuous-time process or a discrete-time process and $\{W_t\}$ is a white noise process with autocorrelation function $\delta_t$, the Dirac delta or Kronecker delta.  Thus, for a discrete-time process, the $\{W_t\}$'s are a sequence of independent zero-mean unit-variance random variables, and $X_t$ is the sum (not the *average*) of the current and the past three values of the noise driving the system. If we truly want the average of these values to get the *moving average*, we should scale $X_t$ by a factor of $\frac 14$.

Don't believe a word of all this?

With $X_t = W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3}$, we have that
\begin{align}
\gamma(0) &= E[X_tX_t]\\ 
&= E[(W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3})(W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3})]\\
&= E[W_t^2 + W_{t-1}^2+ W_{t-2}^2 + W_{t-3}^2]\\
&= 4,\\
\gamma(1) &= E[X_tX_{t+1}]\\ 
&= E[(W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3})(W_{t+1} + W_{t}+ W_{t-1} + W_{t-2})]\\
&= E[W_t^2 + W_{t-1}^2+ W_{t-2}^2]\\
&= 3\\
\gamma(2) &= E[X_tX_{t+2}]\\ 
&= E[(W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3})(W_{t+2} + W_{t+1}+ W_{t} + W_{t-1})]\\
&= E[W_t^2 + W_{t-1}^2]\\
&= 2\\
\gamma(3) &= E[X_tX_{t+3}]\\ 
&= E[(W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3})(W_{t+3} + W_{t+2}+ W_{t+1} + W_{t}]\\
&= E[W_t^2 ]\\
&= 1\\
\gamma(4) &= E[X_tX_{t+4}]\\ 
&= E[(W_t + W_{t-1}+ W_{t-2} + W_{t-3})(W_{t+4} + W_{t+3}+ W_{t+2} + W_{t+1}]\\
&= 0\\
\end{align} exactly as it should be.